# BoxConstraints has a negative minimum width

Tags: flutter

in this class as an widget which i use animation to show and hide, when i multiple show or hiding by click, sometimes i get this error:

> BoxConstraints has a negative minimum width.The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=-0.8, 0.0<=h<=Infinity; NOT NORMALIZED)

this part of code has problem

```
child: Row( //<--- problem cause on this line of code
   children: <Widget>[
      ...
   ],
),
```

My class code:

```
class FollowingsStoryList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Stories> _stories;

  FollowingsStoryList({@required List<Stories> stories}) : _stories = stories;

  @override
  _FollowingsStoryListState createState() => _FollowingsStoryListState();
}

class _FollowingsStoryListState extends State<FollowingsStoryList> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Stories> get stories => widget._stories;
  bool _isExpanded = false;
  AnimationController _barrierController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _barrierController = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400), vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      curve: _isExpanded ? Curves.elasticOut : Curves.elasticIn,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedContainer(
            curve: _isExpanded ? Curves.elasticOut : Curves.elasticIn,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
            width: _isExpanded ? 90 : 1,
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 65.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
              ],
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: _toggleExpanded,
            child: StoriesShapeBorder(
              alignment: Alignment(1, 0.60),
              icon: Icons.adjust,
              color: Colors.white,
              barWidth: 4,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _toggleExpanded() {
    setState(() {
      _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
      if (_isExpanded) {
        _barrierController.forward();
      } else {
        _barrierController.reverse();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `Curves.elasticOut` and `Curves.elasticIn` are

> oscillating curves that grows/shrinks in magnitude while **overshooting**
>   its bounds.

When `_isExpanded` is false, you are expecting the width to go from 90 to 1 however `Curves.elasticOut` overshoots and becomes much less than 1 (hence a negative width) for a short period of time.

This is what is causing the error imho. Plus for what reason do you have nested `AnimatedContainer`s? Top `AnimatedContainer` seems unnecessary.

Try getting rid of the top `AnimatedContainer` and changing all 4 of the `Curves` to `Curves.linear` and I think your error will be gone. Actually you can use any `Curves` which don't overshoot.

If you really need Elastic Curve, then maybe this would work too:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedContainer(
            curve: _isExpanded ? Curves.elasticOut : Curves.easeInSine,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
            width: _isExpanded ? 90 : 1,
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 65.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
              ],
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: _toggleExpanded,
            child: StoriesShapeBorder(
              alignment: Alignment(1, 0.60),
              icon: Icons.adjust,
              color: Colors.white,
              barWidth: 4,
            ),
         ),
       ],
    );
  }
```

Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use AnimatedController, to (oddly enough) control your animation value and set minimum value "0".

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

double getValue(...) {
  // some logic / curves
  // ....

  return math.max(0, value);
}
```